# The number of solutions for $\tan x +\sec x =2\cos x$

Tags: trigonometry

$$\sin x +1=2\cos^2x$$
$$\sin x =-1,\frac 12$$

But at $x=270$, value of tan isn’t defined, thus there should be only 2 solutions. The answer is 3, and includes 270. This seems very straightforward, but I just wanted to make sure I am not missing anything. Thanks!

Comment: $\tan 270 ^ \circ$ is defined  . See [Google](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enIN763IN763&sxsrf=ACYBGNQYm1HHE7YHnZbkmnNIXad7FAQs2w%3A1576256963432&ei=w8XzXeLuGYvjz7sP5Kyb4AU&q=tan+270+degrees+&oq=tan+270+degrees+&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39j0l2j0i22i30l3.1850.2021..2350...0.2..0.248.489.2-2......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.dtXp31-PqVg&ved=0ahUKEwii3ITjjrPmAhWL8XMBHWTWBlwQ4dUDCAs&uact=5)

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit That may be the maximum limit of the Google calculator :)

Comment: It is probably an error

Comment: Cool. Just needed to be sure

Answer (score 1):

It is true if you consider the **closure** of the difference $\tan x +\sec x -2\cos x$ -- that is, you include points where the function is not defined but we can plug in a value that makes it continuous, by taking a limit.

We thereby find a limit of $0$ at $270°$ along with what are usually considered the solutions at $30°$ and $150°$.  Note that even though we multiplied by $\cos x$, the closure gives only $270°$ as an additional solution; taking the limit does not work at $90°$.

Related concepts: [removable singularity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RemovableSingularity.html), [sinc function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SincFunction.html).

Answer (score 0):

It is $$\sin(x)+1=2(1-\sin^2(x))$$ after multiplying by $$\cos(x)$$